# L2 norm inequality of matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Recently I am reading a paper, the author make such assumption :$\lambda$ is a positive such that $\left\| I-\lambda BB^{T} \right \| _{2} < 1$, where $B$ is $m\times d$ matrix. I want to figure out the range of $\lambda$. I think $0<\lambda< \frac{2}{\left\| BB^{T}\right \| _{2} }$, but i dont know how to prove it strictly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using SVD of $BB^T$, we have $U\Sigma U^T = BB^T$, then
\begin{align}
\|I - \lambda BB^T\|_2  &= \|UU^T - \lambda U\Sigma U^T\|_2 \\
&= \|I - \lambda \Sigma\|_2 < 1.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$\lambda < \frac{2}{\sigma_\max(BB^T)} = \frac{2}{\|BB^T\|_2}$.